# allowing CORS request with Flask and React

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors

I am trying to connect a client with a server via `ajax` requests.

My client, running on `localhost:8080`, has a button which invokes a function that does a simple `ajax` request to a locally running server, `localhost:5000`.

onClick function:

```
  handleClick() {
console.log("check flights button was clicked!");
console.log(this.state);
const baseUrl = 'localhost:5000'
ajax.get(`${baseUrl}/flights/${this.state.origin}_${this.state.destination}`)
.end((error, response) => {
  if (!error && response) {
    console.log('got a valid response from the server')
  } else {
    console.log(`Error fetching data from the server: `, error)
  }
});}
```

the (very) simple server, implemented with `Flask`, is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Flights(Resource):
    def get(self, origin, destination):
    answer = 'we got some data ' + origin + ' ' + destination
    print answer

api.add_resource(Flights, '/flights/<string:origin>_<string:destination>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I can access the server if i simply go to `localhost:5000/flights/origin_destination`, which prints a message saying it received the origin and destination.
However, when I try to do the `ajax` request, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:5000/flights/Porto_Lisboa. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Any suggestions on how to correct this behaviour?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error suggest, you're missing the protocol name in your request. Try to add it at the start of the string :

```
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000'
```

instead of just `localhost:5000`

Comment: you are correct, i actually found that on the same time by googling some more, and now i get this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/flights/Porto_Lisboa. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
Googling it right now

Comment: It's the server task to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header so that clients can request it. If you're using Flask, you can take a look at https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for example.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. The client refuses to read the request because the server didn't answer with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: thank you for your answers, they were very  helpful!

Comment: Hi @RafaelMarques if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.